# How do I make the event listeners work for the appended elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have set up a shopping cart and I'm trying to get the items to add and remove items. The items I appended on the event listeners are not working. In my Javascipt, I have the sliding animation for when you click the cart button. Then I have a for loop for all the input fields to be marked as one. Then I have two functions that are the 'addtocart' and 'remove' and they are self explanatory

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>E-Commerce Website</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/all.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"async></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="p1">
            <div class="topnavcont">
                <ul class="topleftnav">
                <li class="topnavlink">Home</li>
                <li class="topnavlink">Shop</li>
            </ul>
            <h1 class="topnavtitle">The Store</h1>
            <div class="navcartcontainer">
                <h3 class="totalnumber">3</h3>
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cartbtn"></i>
            </div>
            </div>

            <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="bgimg">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="cartbody">
                <i class="fal fa-times" id="closeicon"></i>
                <h2 class="carttitle">Shopping Cart</h2>
                <ul class="cartitems">
                    <li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt1</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li>
                    <li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt2</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number"class="qinput"id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li>
                    <li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt3</span><span class="itemprice">$8.99</span><input type="number" class="qinput" id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="carttotal">Total: $64.66</div>
                
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="p2">
    <h1 class="p2title">My Shop</h1>
    <div class="itemcontainer">
<div class="item">
    <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Shirt1</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Shirt2</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Shirt3</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

</div>
    <div class="itemcontainer2">
<div class="item">
    <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Shirt4</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Shirt5</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="clark-street-mercantile-vC-GqGbakJo-unsplash.jpg" alt="" class="item-img">
    <h1 class="item-title">Shirt6</h1>
    <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
    <button class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
</div>

</div>

</div>


    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}
.wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.topnavcont{
    padding: 1em 0em;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 0px 3px 6px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
}


.topleftnav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: -3%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.topleftnav li{
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.05rem;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    border-bottom: transparent solid 2px;
}
.topleftnav li:hover{
    border-bottom: black solid 2px;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.topnavtitle{
    margin-right: 2.5%;
}
.navcartcontainer{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: -1%;
    
}
.topnavcont .totalnumber{
    color: black;
    padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    height: fit-content;
    /* cursor: pointer; */
    font-weight: bold;
}

.topnavcont i{
    font-size: 2rem; 
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    
}
.topnavcont i:hover{
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
.p1{
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.p1 img{
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
.p1 .overlay::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vh;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.4;
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
}
.cartbody{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 25vw;
    top: 10%;
    left: 75%;
    z-index: 2100;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: 0.7s ease;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0px 3px 6px;

}
.carttotal{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: rgb(22, 113, 119);
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
}
.cartbody i{
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    margin-left: 0.4em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.cartbody i:hover{
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
.cartbody input{
    width: 2.2rem;
    height: auto;
}
.cartbodyactive{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
.carttitle{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.cartitem{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.cartitem .itemtitle{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.cartitems{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 3em;
    overflow-y: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}
.removebtn{
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.p2{
    height: 160vh;
    position: relative;
}
.p2title{
    color: black;
    padding-top: 2.5em;
    margin-left: 7%;
}
.p2 img{
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
.itemcontainer{
    margin-top: 6em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.itemcontainer2{
    margin-top: 6em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 355px;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.atcbtn{
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: black solid 2px;
    padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.atcbtn:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
let TotalNumber = document.querySelector('.totalnumber');
const Atc = document.getElementsByClassName('atcbtn');
const cartbtn = document.getElementById('cartbtn')
const closeicon = document.getElementById('closeicon')
const cartbody = document.querySelector('.cartbody')
const removebtn = document.getElementsByClassName('removebtn')
const carttotal = document.querySelector('.carttotal')
let   qinput = document.getElementsByClassName('qinput')

cartbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    cartbody.classList.toggle('cartbodyactive')
})

closeicon.addEventListener('click', function(){
    cartbody.classList.remove('cartbodyactive')
})



for(let i = 0; i < qinput.length; i++){
    qinput[i].value= 1;
}




function removeitem(){



    for (i = 0; i < removebtn.length; i++){
        let rbutton = removebtn[i];
        rbutton.addEventListener("click", function (){
            let TotalNumbervalue = TotalNumber.innerHTML 
            if(TotalNumbervalue > 0){
                TotalNumber.innerHTML--
                console.log('if statement for negative works')
            }
    
            rbutton.parentElement.remove()
        })
    }
}
    removeitem()




function additemtocart(){




for (i = 0; i < Atc.length; i++){
    let button = Atc[i];
    button.addEventListener("click", function (){
        let TotalNumbervalue = TotalNumber.innerHTML 
        if(TotalNumbervalue > -1){
            
            TotalNumber.innerHTML++
        }
        let shopitem = button.parentElement
        let shoptitle = shopitem.getElementsByClassName('item-title')[0].innerText
        let shopprice = shopitem.getElementsByClassName('itemprice')[0].innerText
        let cartrow = document.createElement('div')
        let cartitems = document.getElementsByClassName('cartitems')[0]
        let cartrowcontent = `<li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">${shoptitle}</span><span class="itemprice">${shopprice}</span><input type="number" id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li>`
        cartrow.innerHTML = cartrowcontent
        cartitems.append(cartrow)
    })
}

}


additemtocart()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your logic significantly by using [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) (see: [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)). You add a single eventListener to the document body (or any shared ancestor of the buttons/events you want to delegate) and based on the target of the event trigger the appropriate callbacks.

```
function addItemToCart(item) {
  console.log('add: ', item);
  // ...
}

function removeItemFromCart(item) {
  console.log('remove: ', item);
  // ...
}

function handleDocumentClick(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('atcbtn')) {
    addItemToCart(event.target.parentElement);
  }
  if (event.target.classList.contains('removebtn')) {
    removeItemFromCart(event.target.parentElement);
  }
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick);
```

With this simple method you no longer need to know how many items/buttons are in the cart or shop, they will all trigger their relevant callback.

You'll also note that in the above we are passing the `event.target.parentElement` to the callback meaning we can get right to work with the `item` without further querying in the callbacks.

The next efficiency that you might want to take advantage of, and which the snippet below relies on is [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). I've added the `title` and `price` of each item to the parent div as data attributes, which allows us to access these details with out querying child elements for their content.

```html
<div class="item" data-price="12.99" data-title="Shirt 2">
  ...
</div>
```

All that remains then, is to write the logic for adding/removing items from the cart and updating the related cart count in the header, and cart total in the cart.

The snippet here doesn't handle the changing of quantity in the cart, but perhaps you can see how you might use delegation to add on to the logic...

It's a lot to write your own cart and handle validation etc along the way, you might want to look at templating libraries or cart solutions ([snipcart](https://snipcart.com) comes to mind).

```js
const cartbody = document.querySelector('.cartbody');
const cartbtn = document.getElementById('cartbtn');
const closeicon = document.getElementById('closeicon');

cartbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  cartbody.classList.toggle('cartbodyactive');
});

closeicon.addEventListener('click', function () {
  cartbody.classList.remove('cartbodyactive');
});

const totalNumber = document.querySelector('.totalnumber');
const cartItemsUl = document.querySelector('.cartitems');
const cartTotal = document.querySelector('.carttotal');

function addItemToCart(item) {
  console.log('add: ', item);

  const { price, title } = item.dataset;
  const itemLi = document.createElement('li');
  itemLi.className = 'cartitem';
  itemLi.dataset.title = title;
  itemLi.dataset.price = price;
  itemLi.innerHTML = `<span class="itemtitle">${title}</span>
    <span class="itemprice">$${price}</span>
    <input type="number" class="qinput" id="qinput" value="1">
    <button type="button" class="removebtn">Remove</button>`;
  cartItemsUl.appendChild(itemLi);

  // update item count
  totalNumber.textContent = +totalNumber.textContent + 1;

  // update cart total
  const updatedTotal = (parseFloat(cartTotal.dataset.total) + parseFloat(price)).toFixed(2);
  cartTotal.dataset.total = updatedTotal;
  cartTotal.textContent = `$${updatedTotal}`;
}

function removeItemFromCart(item) {
  console.log('remove: ', item);

  const { price, title } = item.dataset;

  item.remove()

  // update item count
  // will need to account for the quantity input value
  totalNumber.textContent = +totalNumber.textContent - 1;

  // update cart total
  const updatedTotal = (parseFloat(cartTotal.dataset.total) - parseFloat(price)).toFixed(2);
  cartTotal.dataset.total = updatedTotal;
  cartTotal.textContent = `$${updatedTotal}`;
}

function handleDocumentClick(event) {
  console.clear();
  if (event.target.classList.contains('atcbtn')) addItemToCart(event.target.parentElement);
  if (event.target.classList.contains('removebtn')) removeItemFromCart(event.target.parentElement);
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick);
```

```css
*{ padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}::-webkit-scrollbar{ display: none;}.wrapper{ overflow-x: hidden;}.topnavcont{ padding: 1em 0em; align-items: center; height: 10vh; width: 100vw; display: flex; justify-content: space-around; background-color: white; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20) 0px 3px 6px; position: fixed; z-index: 5;}.topleftnav{ display: flex; justify-content: space-between; width: 10%; margin-left: -3%; font-weight: bold;}.topleftnav li{ cursor: pointer; list-style: none; font-size: 1.05rem; transition: 0.3s ease; border-bottom: transparent solid 2px;}.topleftnav li:hover{ border-bottom: black solid 2px; transform: scale(1.1);}.topnavtitle{ margin-right: 2.5%;}.navcartcontainer{ display: flex; margin-right: -1%; }.topnavcont .totalnumber{ color: black; padding: 0.2em 0.4em; border-radius: 50%; font-size: 1.25rem; height: fit-content; /* cursor: pointer; */ font-weight: bold;}.topnavcont i{ font-size: 2rem; margin-left: 0.3em; cursor: pointer; transition: 0.4s ease; }.topnavcont i:hover{ transform: scale(1.15);}.p1{ height: 100vh; position: relative;}.p1 img{ object-fit: cover; height: 100vh; width: 100%;}.p1 .overlay::after{ content: ""; position: absolute; top: 10vh; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; background-color: black; opacity: 0.4; height: 90vh; width: 100%;}.cartbody{ background-color: white; position: fixed; height: 100vh; width: 25vw; top: 10%; left: 75%; z-index: 2100; overflow-y: auto; transform: translateX(100%); transition: 0.7s ease; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30) 0px 3px 6px;}.carttotal{ font-size: 2rem; color: rgb(22, 113, 119); font-weight: bold; margin-top: 1.5em; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 3em;}.cartbody i{ font-size: 2.2rem; margin-left: 0.4em; margin-top: 0.2em; color: black; font-weight: 200; cursor: pointer; transition: 0.3s ease;}.cartbody i:hover{ transform: scale(1.15);}.cartbody input{ width: 2.2rem; height: auto;}.cartbodyactive{ transform: translateX(0%);}.carttitle{ text-align: center; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 2em;}.cartitem{ display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly;}.cartitem .itemtitle{ font-size: 1.2rem;}.cartitems{ display: flex; flex-direction: column; row-gap: 3em; overflow-y: auto; list-style: none; padding-left: 0.5em;}.removebtn{ background-color: red; color: black; font-weight: bold; outline: none; border: none; padding: 0.5em 1em; cursor: pointer;}.p2{ height: 160vh; position: relative;}.p2title{ color: black; padding-top: 2.5em; margin-left: 7%;}.p2 img{ height: 200px; width: 300px;}.itemcontainer{ margin-top: 6em; display: flex; justify-content: space-around;}.itemcontainer2{ margin-top: 6em; display: flex; justify-content: space-around;}.item{ display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; min-height: 355px; justify-content: space-around;}.atcbtn{ background-color: white; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; color: black; width: 40%; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; border: black solid 2px; padding: 0.8em 0.5em; transition: 0.4s ease;}.atcbtn:hover{ background-color: black; color: white; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>E-Commerce Website</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="app.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="p1">
      <div class="topnavcont">
        <ul class="topleftnav">
          <li class="topnavlink">Home</li>
          <li class="topnavlink">Shop</li>
        </ul>
        <h1 class="topnavtitle">The Store</h1>
        <div class="navcartcontainer">
          <h3 class="totalnumber">1</h3>
          <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cartbtn"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200/?sig=0" alt="" class="bgimg">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="cartbody">
        <i class="fal fa-times" id="closeicon"></i>
        <h2 class="carttitle">Shopping Cart</h2>
        <ul class="cartitems">
          <li class="cartitem" data-title="Shirt 2" data-price="12.99"><span class="itemtitle">Shirt 2</span>
            <span class="itemprice">$12.99</span>
            <input type="number" class="qinput" id="qinput" value="1">
            <button type="button" class="removebtn">Remove</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="carttotal" data-total="12.99">Total: $12.99</div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="p2">
      <h1 class="p2title">My Shop</h1>
      <div class="itemcontainer">
        <div class="item" data-price="8.99" data-title="Shirt 1">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200/?sig=1" alt="" class="item-img">
          <h1 class="item-title">Shirt 1</h1>
          <h3 class="itemprice">$8.99</h3>
          <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
          <button type="button" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="item" data-price="12.99" data-title="Shirt 2">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200/?sig=2" alt="" class="item-img">
          <h1 class="item-title">Shirt 2</h1>
          <h3 class="itemprice" data-price="12.99">$12.99</h3>
          <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
          <button type="button" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
        </div>

        <div class="item" data-price="3.99" data-title="Shirt 3">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200/?sig=3" alt="" class="item-img">
          <h1 class="item-title">Shirt 3</h1>
          <h3 class="itemprice" data-price="3.99">$3.99</h3>
          <!-- <a href="#" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</a> -->
          <button type="button" class="atcbtn">Add To Cart</button>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are running removeitem() once you load the page. So, it runs through document.getElementsByClassName('removebtn') and returns the *remove buttons* that we have on the page when we first load it.

That's why you can remove items that were already in the cart, but you can't remove new items - those new items have *remove buttons* that were not iterated by the *for... in* loop.

You can fix that by simply adding removeitem() at the bottom of the callback function inside the eventListener from Atc, so every time you add a new item to the cart, removeitem will run again and iterate through every remove button in the page, including new ones. Hope it makes sense!

It will look like this:

```
function additemtocart() {
 


    for (i = 0; i < Atc.length; i++) {
        let button = Atc[i];
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            let TotalNumbervalue = TotalNumber.innerHTML
            if (TotalNumbervalue > -1) {

                TotalNumber.innerHTML++
            }
            let shopitem = button.parentElement
            let shoptitle = shopitem.getElementsByClassName('item-title')[0].innerText
            let shopprice = shopitem.getElementsByClassName('itemprice')[0].innerText
            let cartrow = document.createElement('div')
            let cartitems = document.getElementsByClassName('cartitems')[0]
            let cartrowcontent = `<li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">${shoptitle}</span><span class="itemprice">${shopprice}</span><input type="number" id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li>`
            cartrow.innerHTML = cartrowcontent
            cartitems.append(cartrow)
            removeitem();
        })

    }

}


additemtocart()
```

**EDIT**

> How can I do the same with the '''''for(let i = 0; i < qinput.length; i++){ qinput[i].value= 1; }''''' I added it to the bottom of the function as well but the input value is not updataing

So, when you are defining *cartrowcontent* inside the Atc's eventListener, you are not setting qinput class, just the id =>

```
let cartrowcontent = `<li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">${shoptitle}</span><span class="itemprice">${shopprice}</span><input type="number" id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li>`
```

What I did:

involved qinput loop in a function:

```
function updateQInput() {
    for (let i = 0; i < qinput.length; i++) {
        qinput[i].value = 1;
    }
}

updateQInput();
```

And called it at the bottom of Atc's eventListener (after adding the class "qinput"):

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let TotalNumbervalue = TotalNumber.innerHTML
    if (TotalNumbervalue > -1) {

        TotalNumber.innerHTML++
    }
    let shopitem = button.parentElement
    let shoptitle = shopitem.getElementsByClassName('item-title')[0].innerText
    let shopprice = shopitem.getElementsByClassName('itemprice')[0].innerText
    let cartrow = document.createElement('div')
    let cartitems = document.getElementsByClassName('cartitems')[0]
    let cartrowcontent = `<li class="cartitem"><span class="itemtitle">${shoptitle}</span><span class="itemprice">${shopprice}</span><input type="number" class="qinput" id="qinput"><button class="removebtn">Remove</button></li>`
    cartrow.innerHTML = cartrowcontent
    cartitems.append(cartrow)
    removeitem();
    updateQInput();
}
```

Comment: How can I do the same with the      '''''for(let i = 0; i < qinput.length; i++){
    qinput[i].value= 1;
}'''''       I added it to the bottom of the function as well but the input value is not updataing

Comment: it is not updating because inside de eventListener of Atc you are defining cartrowcontent's input "qinput" without a class =>

</span><input type="number" id="qinput">

I am going to edit my answer to get that, please check it out